# Show one column and multiple column result is different by sort multiply in mysql

Tags: mysql

Why A and B are in different order?

```
（1）sql1
mysql> select postid from mytable where uid=1302754505 order by check_status asc, postid desc limit 15;
+---------------------+
| postid             |
+---------------------+
| 6478974144597095625 |
| 6478973839654417609 |
| 6477718983354512585 |
| 6477718467958437065 |
| 6475650432615478473 |
| 6475650174917440713 |
| 6475649947284174025 |
| 6471209260337755337 |
| 6478983597820114121 |
+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)

（2）sql2
mysql> select postid, check_status from mytable where uid=1302754505 order by check_status asc, postid desc limit 15;
+---------------------+--------------+
| postid             | check_status |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 6478983597820114121 |            0 |
| 6477718983354512585 |            1 |
| 6477718467958437065 |            1 |
| 6475650432615478473 |            1 |
| 6475650174917440713 |            1 |
| 6475649947284174025 |            1 |
| 6471209260337755337 |            1 |
| 6478974144597095625 |            5 |
| 6478973839654417609 |            5 |
+---------------------+--------------+
```

The check_status is not sorted in sql1? I don't understand why sql1 and sql2 result is different.

Comment: What MySql Version are you using?

Comment: @Cataklysim MySql Version is 5.5.9.

Comment: Could you change `LIMIT 15` to `LIMIT 0,15` on both queries and look up the change? For Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: @Cataklysim, I try limit 15 and limit 0,15, it is not effect. This result is not related from limit.You can try insert my data, then you can try sql1 and sql2.

Comment: can you post the `CREATE TABLE` command for `mytable`?

Comment: @SebastianBroschOh my god, our mysql-proxy fix some sql, so I get some different result.I close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our mysql-proxy fix some sql, so I get some different result.